# How to measure CPU usage and memory for a process using .NET Core 3.1 for Windows, Linux and macOS?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, macos, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to get CPU and RAM utilization in Windows, Linux and macOS. Also I need SQL Server(Sqlservr) process CPU and RAM utilization. I am trying this in ASP.NET Core 3.1 but not able to found any solution. I am able to get dot net application CPU and RAM usage using the below command

```
dotnet counters monitor --process-id 11812 --providers MyEventCounter
```

Refered link : https://www.stefangeiger.ch/2020/05/07/dotnet-diagnostics-tools-counters.html . Please suggest me the solution or any other technology to get this done. Environment used: Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 3.1 .

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dotnet-counters collect --process-id 1902 --refresh-interval 3 --format csv
```

Reference document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters#examples

Comment: Thank you @Do Nhu Vy. After executing above commnad following error occured: [ERROR] System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.ConnectInternal(Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 startTime)
   at System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32 timeout)
   at Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client.PidIpcEndpoint.Connect(TimeSpan timeout) in /_/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.NETCore.Client/DiagnosticsIpc/IpcTransport.cs:line 133

Comment: Let's see https://github.com/dotnet/crank/issues/6 it is may be a bug.